# Slick grid mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I am adding styles to some of the cells. But on sorting or filtering, the styles are only fixed to the cell number and not to the actual value.

e.g:

If cell number 2 of row 8th is given style. On sorting, that cell moves to number 2. Though, it doesn't change the position of styled cell. Still cell number 2 of row 8th is styled.

I know there are functions for mapping ids to rows and vice versa. Can anyone tell me how to actually use it.

Comment: I got solution to it. There is a function in DataView: dataView.getRowById(rowId)

Comment: Add this as an answer and close this question.

Comment: I can not close my question by my answer before 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out solution to it. There is following function in DataView:

```
dataView.getRowById(rowID);
```

This gives the current row displayed. If it is hidden by filter, then it will be undefined.